# Chrome Extension: How to get page content of current tab from devtools when requests finished?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm developing a chrome extension to verify page content of current tab from devtools when request finishes. I'm only interested in following types of requests: [main_frame, sub_frame, and xmlhttprequest](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/webRequest.html#type-RequestFilter).

It can be done like this:

1. listen for `chrome.webRequest.onCompleted` event in background.js and filter out non-interested requests
2. communicate with contentScript.js to get the page content
3. send page content as a message to devtools

But will such situation happen?

1. In background.js, request A completes and send a message M_A to contentScript.js to get page content.
2. Request B completes and page content changed.
3. In contentScript.js, M_A is received, then ...

So I want to find a better way, like put all the logic in devtools:

```
var requestFinishedHandler = function(request) {
    // do something here ...
}
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(requestFinishedHandler);
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.onResourceAdded](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow.html). I use it [in DevTools Autosave](https://github.com/NV/chrome-devtools-autosave/blob/8b9504c2bb703d72b7367b4ff801e273257fd5e6/chrome/devtools.js#L178). It doesn’t specify request type such as main_frame, sub_frame, and xmlhttprequest.